# No logro redirigir al login en Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente Clientes y uno Dashboard y luego el de login, pero no logro redirigir al login en caso de que no haya ingresado:

Tengo una carpeta security con un archivo auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router,CanActivate,ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable ({providedIn:'root'})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

    constructor(private route : Router){


    }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
        this.route.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y este es mi app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule,Input } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// material
import { MatSidenavModule } from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatListModule } from "@angular/material/list";
import { MatTooltipModule } from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table' ;
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card' ;
import { MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog' ;
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
// components
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { SidenavComponent } from "./sidenav/sidenav.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { ClienteComponent } from './cliente/cliente.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { DialogClienteComponent } from "./cliente/dialog/dialogcliente.component";
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { DialogDeleteComponent } from "./cliente/common/dialogdelete.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "Home",
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "Clientes",
    component: ClienteComponent,
  },
  
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogClienteComponent,
    DialogDeleteComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ClienteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' }),
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,


   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

no se si alguien puede ayudarme, si necesitan otro codigo edito la pregunta.

Mi app.routing tiene lo siguiente:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ClienteComponent } from './cliente/cliente.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './security/auth.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
  {path: 'home',component:HomeComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'Clientes',component:ClienteComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'login',component:LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Ahi muestro mi login component:

```
import {Component,  OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { ApiAuthService } from "../services/apiauth.service";

@Component({templateUrl:'login.component.html'})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
  
    public user!: string;
    public password!: string;
    constructor(public apiauth:ApiAuthService,
        private router:Router){
          if (this.apiauth.usuarioData){
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        
         
       
    }
    login(){
        this.apiauth.login(this.user,this.password).subscribe(response =>{
            if (response.exito===1)   {
                 this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
            });
       
    }
}
```

Y mi apiauthservice.ts:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { BehaviorSubject,  map,  Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Usuario } from "../models/usuario";
import { Response } from "../models/response";
const httpOption = {
    headers :new HttpHeaders({
   
   
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    })
  }
@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
export class ApiAuthService{
   url: string = 'https://localhost:44355/Login' ;
   private usuarioSubject!: BehaviorSubject<Usuario>;
   public get usuarioData():Usuario{
     return this.usuarioSubject.value;
   }
   constructor(private http : HttpClient){
        this.usuarioSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Usuario>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario')!));
   }
   login(user: string, password:string):Observable<Response>{
       return this.http.post<Response>(this.url, {user,password},httpOption).pipe(map(res=>{
         if(res.exito === 1){
            const usuario:Usuario = res.data;
            localStorage.setItem('usuario',JSON.stringify(usuario));
            this.usuarioSubject.next(usuario);
         }
         return res;
       }));
  
   }
   logout(){
     localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
     this.usuarioSubject.next(null!);
   }
}
```

El canActivate quedo asi pero sigue sin funcionar:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
        const usuario = this.apiauthservice.usuarioData;
        if (usuario){
            return true;
        }else{
        this.route.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: En el `canActivate` agrega el código que usas para saber si un usuario está logueado.

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta, muestro el canActivate pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega el `/` para completar la ruta.

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
            const usuario = this.apiauthservice.usuarioData;
            if (usuario){
               return true;
            }else{
              this.route.navigate(['/login']);
              return false;
            } 
    }
```

Comment: Tampoco me funciona. Si bien no sé muestran los datos no me redirige al login..tengo que ir manualmente..

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la variable route que recibe tu canActivate es la del problema, ya que estarias usando la del metodo y no la del constructor, tu varible router se convertiria a una variable de scoop. Espero te funcione.

```
canActivate(): boolean{

    this.route.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte..Tampoco funciona..si pongo un alert por ejemplo dentro del canActivate no me muestra nada tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciono modificando app.module.ts, agregando el `AuthGuard` en las rutas, aunque el tutorial que vi lo tenia en app.routing.ts tal como publique en la pregunta:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
 path: "Home",
 canActivate: [AuthGuard],
 component: HomeComponent,
},
{
  path: "login",
  component: LoginComponent,
},
{
path: "Clientes",
component: ClienteComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},

];
```